# Aggregating dicts within a list based on key value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm struggling to wrap my head around this one. I've got a list with multiple dictionaries that I would like to aggregate based on two values. Example code:

```
>>> data = [
...     { "regex": ".*ccc-r.*", "age": 44, "count": 224 },
...     { "regex": ".*nft-r.*", "age": 23, "count": 44 },
...     { "regex": ".*ccc-r.*", "age": 44, "count": 20 },
...     { "regex": ".*ccc-r.*", "age": 32, "count": 16 },
...     { "regex": ".*nft-r.*", "age": 23, "count": 46 },
...     { "regex": ".*zxy-r.*", "age": 16, "count": 55 }
...     ]
```

I'm trying to aggregate dicts that have the same age and regex and adding the count key across all instances. Example output would be:

```
>>> data = [
...     { "regex": ".*ccc-r.*", "age": 44, "count": 244 },
...     { "regex": ".*nft-r.*", "age": 23, "count": 90 },
...     { "regex": ".*ccc-r.*", "age": 32, "count": 16 },
...     { "regex": ".*zxy-r.*", "age": 16, "count": 55 }
...     ]
```

Would like to do this without pandas or addon modules, would prefer a solution from the std lib if at all possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do not want to use any imports, you can first collect the data in a dictionary `aggregated_data` in which the key will be a tuple of `(regex, age)`, and the value will be the `count`. Once you have formed this dictionary, you can form back the original structure you had:

```py
data = [
    { "regex": ".*ccc-r.*", "age": 44, "count": 224 },
    { "regex": ".*nft-r.*", "age": 23, "count": 44 },
    { "regex": ".*ccc-r.*", "age": 44, "count": 20 },
    { "regex": ".*ccc-r.*", "age": 32, "count": 16 },
    { "regex": ".*nft-r.*", "age": 23, "count": 46 },
    { "regex": ".*zxy-r.*", "age": 16, "count": 55 }
]

aggregated_data = {}

for dictionary in data:
    key = (dictionary['regex'], dictionary['age'])
    aggregated_data[key] = aggregated_data.get(key, 0) + dictionary['count']

data = [{'regex': key[0], 'age': key[1], 'count': value} for key, value in aggregated_data.items()]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
data = [{'regex': '.*ccc-r.*', 'age': 44, 'count': 224}, {'regex': '.*nft-r.*', 'age': 23, 'count': 44}, {'regex': '.*ccc-r.*', 'age': 44, 'count': 20}, {'regex': '.*ccc-r.*', 'age': 32, 'count': 16}, {'regex': '.*nft-r.*', 'age': 23, 'count': 46}, {'regex': '.*zxy-r.*', 'age': 16, 'count': 55}]
for i in data:
   d[(i['regex'], i['age'])] += i['count']

r = [{'regex':a, 'age':b, 'count':c} for (a, b), c in d.items()]
```

Output:

```
[{'regex': '.*ccc-r.*', 'age': 44, 'count': 244}, 
 {'regex': '.*nft-r.*', 'age': 23, 'count': 90}, 
 {'regex': '.*ccc-r.*', 'age': 32, 'count': 16}, 
 {'regex': '.*zxy-r.*', 'age': 16, 'count': 55}]
```

Comment: this is beautiful, thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try,

```
agg = {}

for d in data:
    if agg.get(d['regex']):
        agg[d['regex']]['count'] += d['count']
    else:
        agg[d['regex']] = d

print(agg.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using a library (and a slightly different output) this can be done nicely with `pandas`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data.groupby(['regex', 'age']).sum()
```

This yields

```
               count
regex     age
.*ccc-r.* 32      16
          44     244
.*nft-r.* 23      90
.*zxy-r.* 16      55
```